# Embed heredoc in docker-compose yaml file

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, heredoc

I would like to embed a HEREDOC in a docker-compose yaml file.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  test-cli:
    image: ubuntu
    entrypoint: |
      /bin/sh << HERE
      echo hello
      echo goodbye
      HERE
```

When I attempt to run this, I get the following error.

```
 docker-compose -f heredoc.yml run --rm test-cli
Creating network "dspace-compose-v2_default" with the default driver
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open <<
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Contrary to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), it seems the arguments given to entrypoint aren't passed to '/bin/sh -c' but are instead parsed and converted to an array of arguments (argv).

In fact if you run `docker inspect` on the example you provided you can see that your command line was converted into an array:

```
         "Entrypoint": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "<<",
            "HERE",
            "echo",
            "hello",
            "echo",
            "goodbye",
            "HERE"
        ],
```

Since the array of arguments isn't interpreted by a shell you can't use stuff like pipes and HEREDOC.

Instead you could use the features that YAML gives you to deal with multi line input and provide an array of arguments:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  test-cli:
    image: ubuntu
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/bash
      - '-c'
      - |
          echo hello
          echo goodbye
```

If you really need HEREDOC you could do:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  test-cli:
    image: ubuntu
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/bash
      - '-c'
      - |
        /bin/sh << HERE
        echo hello
        echo goodbye
        HERE
```